# Loading a big file in a gcloud application with Flask

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, gcloud

I uploaded a Flask application on the Google app engine which use a scikit learning model. I would like the pickle file to be loaded only once but I don't know where and how to import it.

I tried to import the model at the very beginning of the application script, but then an error occurred on the website.

## main.py :

```py
clf = joblib.load(open("static/troll_model.pkl", "rb"))

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@application.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == "POST":
        message = request.form['message']
        data = [message]
        pred = clf.predict(data)

    return render_template("result.html", prediction=pred)
```

## app.yaml :

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:application

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url : /.*
  script: auto
```

For now, the model is imported each time the client asks for an answer, it works but the application becomes very laggy. I would like to import the file only once.

Comment: "but then an error occurred on the website. " - What was the error?

Comment: The pickle file will need to be loaded into *each* App Engine instance that's created. IIUC this is what's happening with your script by instantiating it into global (which is good). If you wrap `joblib.load(...)` into a function that writes a log entry and execute that on starting, you should see one log entry per instance *not* per request. Although there are alternative ways for you to persist the model, each instance must deserialize the object in order for that instance to use it.

Comment: You should have what you want already. Focus on that error, I suspect your instance is dying with each request, so every request starts a new instance and loads the model.

Comment: What do you mean by "each instance must deserialize the object" ? Do I have to do that manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine if the flex gcloud app engine environment is used. The flex environment allow to use local files (here the scikit learn model), whereas the strict environment does not.